# How to refresh usestate with keydown event listeners in react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I am making a drum machine that is supposed to activate audios when specific keys are pressed and then display the name of the sound. However, everytime the keys are pressed the if statements are not functioning properly because the useStates are not updating when the function / eventlistener is called. I am trying to use useEffect but I'm struggling and it is driving me insane.

To clarify: I am using a function component and not a class object component

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    document.addEventListener('keydown',handleKey)
  }, [bank, power, volume])

  function handleKey(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation() // Stops the function from firing 2+ times
    if (power){               // if the drum machine is on 
      if(bank === true) {const clip = audiosBank.find((clip) => clip.keyCode === e.which); // bank is boolean representing the second audio set
      if (!clip) return;    // clip eg: {keyCode: x, letter: x, name: x, src: x}
      let csound = new Audio(clip.src)
      csound.volume = volume  // Volume is a useState connected to a input element with type range
      csound.play()
      setValue(prev => prev = clip.name)  // Displays the audio name      
}
  }}
```

The problem is that power,bank,and volume are set to their default state, which is true, false, and 0.7 and they are not updating.
Can anyone please tell me the issue that I am not seeing.

Comment: If you think that `setValue(prev => prev = clip.name)` statement does not execute, you should debug you code with `console.log` and tell where do you stop seeing the logs. Anyway, this is indeed the way to listen to keydown event, but you must also detach the listener on component unmount: `return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKey);` - otherwise your application might have dozens of event listeners